# Symmetric powers of odd spheres

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, spheres, rational-homotopy-theory

Given a sufficiently nice space $X$, say a connected and compact polyhedron, one has a [nice formula](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/poincare-polynomial-of-a-symmetric-product/23ADFE283A6840D1AC088A7F4C62E367) for the Poincaré polynomial of the orbit space $SP^n X:= X^n/S_n$ of the $n$-fold Cartesian product under the usual symmetric group action. In particular, writing $b_i$ for the $i$th Betti number of $X$:

$ p_t(SP^nX) = \text{the } x^n \text{ coefficient of } \frac{(1+tx)^{b_1}(1+t^3x)^{b_3} \cdots}{(1-x)(1-t^2x)^{b_2}\cdots}. $

One can then compute that, for $X = S^{2k+1}$ an odd-dimensional sphere, we have

$p_t(SP^n S^{2k+1}) = 1 + t^{2k+1} = p_t(S^{2k+1}).$

In fact, when $k=0$, this equality comes from a homotopy equivalence. There is always the inclusion

$i: X \hookrightarrow SP^nX \qquad i(x) = x + x_2 + \cdots + x_n,$

where the $x_i$ are fixed constants and we use additive notation for elements of $SP^n X$. On the other hand, thinking of $S^1$ as the unit complex numbers, we can write down a retract

$r: SP^nS^1 \to S^1 \qquad r( \, \sum_i x_i \, ) = \prod_i x_i.$

One can then show that $r$ and $i$ together constitute a homotopy equivalence $S^1 \simeq SP^n S^1$.

Now this is all wildly false for even-dimensional spheres. In particular, one can show $SP^n S^2 \cong \mathbb{CP}^n$. Also the previously mentioned homotopy equivalence does not hold for odd spheres: in light of the cofibration (see [these notes](https://www.irio.co.uk/projects/science/Algebraic%20Topology/Mat2000/Infinite_symmetric_product.pdf) if interested)

$ \Sigma^n \mathbb{RP}^{n-1} \to S^n \hookrightarrow SP^2 S^n $

we have the formula $H_*(SP^2(S^n)) \cong H_*(S^n) \oplus \tilde{H}_*(\Sigma^n \mathbb{RP}^{n-1})$, so there is 2-torsion in $SP^2(S^{2k+1})$ whenever $k>0$. However **I'm curious if one can construct a map**

$SP^n S^{2k+1} \to S^{2k+1}$

**inducing an isomorphism on** $H_*(-;\mathbb{Q})$. The only idea I've got, thinking of $S^{2k+1} \subset \mathbb{C}^{k+1}$, is

$f: SP^n S^{2k+1} \to \mathbb{C}^{n(k+1)}-0 \qquad f((b^1_0,\dots,b^1_k)+\cdots+(b^n_0,\dots,b^n_k)) = (\dots, e_i(b_j), \dots),$

where $e_i$ is the $i$th elementary polynomial in $n$ variables and $b_j$ stands for the tuple $(b^1_j,\dots,b^n_j)$, defined up to permutation. This mimics the usual formulas used to show $SP^n \mathbb{C}^m \cong \mathbb{C}^{nm}$.

Of course, in this attempt, the dimension of the image is much too large. The big trouble with directly generalizing to $k>0$ seems to be that **higher-dimensional spheres no longer have an abelian group structure,** and I can't think of an alternative way to take an $n$-tuple of vectors on the sphere and produce a new non-zero vector in a symmetric way.

Comment: This is an excellent question. Your original idea actually works quite well, but you need to pass to the "rational homotopy category". There is a functor on simply connected spaces, called rationalization, which takes $X$ and spits out a space $X \otimes \Bbb Q$ with $\pi_n(X \otimes \Bbb Q) = \pi_n(X) \otimes \Bbb Q$. Then a calculation shows that $S^{2k+1} \otimes \Bbb Q = K(\Bbb Q, 2k+1)$, which *is* a group. On the other hand, I have no idea how symmetric products behave with respect to rationalization.

Comment: Ah, fabulous! This gives me a great direction to start investigating--thank you! Is there a reference you'd recommend for understanding the group structure of $S^{2k+1} \otimes \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I do not have anything in mind: the claim is, essentially, that every Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(G,n)$ for $G$ abelian is in fact an abelian topological group. The easiest way (IMO) to see this is to prove that, in general, if $G$ is an abelian topological group, its classifying space $BG$ is that as well. For that, you want the keywords "(iterated) bar construction". But if you see the definition, you might be able to prove it yourself (by hand). Then the claim is just that $\pi_n S^{2k+1} \otimes \Bbb Q$ is concentrated in degree $n = 2k+1$, which is a theorem of (I belive) Serre.

Comment: (And from there: $B K(G,n) = K(G,n+1)$.) Hopefully someone more expert will be able to say something more useful.

Comment: You might like to check out Milgram's work. For example the paper available here https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/milgram4.pdf, and also his book "Unstable Homotopy From the Stable Point of View".